how to call Api RateCard of Microsoft azure
In postman, I did a GET:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{my-subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2016-08-31-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'
But return 302 Found and in the body, only ""
Anybody knows how resolves?
I try to call for the Rate card, but return 302 found.
Could it be something with my access token?

Do you have follow redirect option enabled?
